# Do I need Openstack's keypair and cloud-init's ssh_authorized_keys together?

Tags: openstack, terraform

I have an older setup using Terraform and Openstack. Via Terraform there will be keypairs injected to Openstack instances:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "bamboo_agent" {
  name               = var.agents[count.index].name
  image_name         = "${var.image}"
  flavor_name        = "${var.flavor}"
  key_pair           = "${openstack_compute_keypair_v2.bamboo_ssh[0].name}"
  user_data          = "${file("scripts/init_instance.cfg")}"
  network {
    port             = "${openstack_networking_port_v2.bamboo[count.index].id}"
  }
  count= length(var.agents)
}
```

And in *scripts/init_instance.cfg* there will be keys added:

```
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa ...
```

AFAIK both methods are doing the same, right? Do I need both? Wouldn't it be enough to remove one of it?

I want to remove the keypair and add the keys via `ssh_authorized_keys` to the default account and via `users:` to further accounts in cloud-init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively they should be doing the same, but as far as I know they won't be applied at the same time.

cloud-init runs in the image/template used to create the new instance and will customise the template with instance specific settings at first boot.  Cloud-init calls on the OpenStack meta-data provider fairly early on and will download meta-data, such as the OpenStack ssh key and your user-data/cloud-config script `scripts/init_instance.cfg`

I think that the SSH key from OpenStack will be applied first.

Since it validates the key before it is accepted relying on OpenStack to deploy a key should be quite robust and reliable. But OpenStack has the limitation that it only allows you to assign a single key to deploy to an instance.

A user-data / cloud-config script such as your `scripts/init_instance.cfg` is the last thing that gets executed by cloud-init.
cloud-config does't have the one key limitation and allows you to assign multiple ssh key's and perform many additional configuration tasks as well.

It might be beneficial to have a key deployed by OpenStack, in case your [cloud-config](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) scripts contains invalid yaml and fails completely  ; you should then still have an instance you can access and debug...

Comment: If anything fails, the whole instance is broken and not compliant. So I will handle it in cloud-config and remove the keypair. Thanks.